# Change urxvt colors

Tags: colors, rxvt

I want to change the colors used by the terminal. I can change colors 0 to 15 in `.Xresources` with commands like:

```
*color0 #abcdef
```

How can I change the RGB hexcode for colors 16+?

Comment: This answers your question: [Can I change the default palette for an xterm-256color terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328752/can-i-change-the-default-palette-for-an-xterm-256color-terminal)